# When using object initializers, what does the parenthesis do?

Tags: c#, constructor, initializer

I've recently found myself using initializers a bit more often than usual, so I thought I'd look into the finer details. I can vaguely remember reading something that Jon Skeet(?) wrote which showed some code that differed only by the inclusion of parenthesis, but behaved differently. It basically looked like:

```
Foo object1 = new Foo   { someValue = true; }
Foo object2 = new Foo() { someValue = true; }
```

What exactly is the difference between these two statements, what is happening under the hood, and why?

Comment: Ah, perfect. I tried to search about 3 different ways but couldn't get quite the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: yep, Eric Lippert answer shold be enough :)